# How to force a left alignment ( menu )?

Tags: css

Actually, I will want to align the titles on the left.

[image]

I know the problem may be this line, but I don't know what properties I should use to fix my problem? :-S

```
.sidebar .nav-links li a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 13px 0;
}
```

On the other hand, the icons are correctly positioned.

CSS

```
.sidebar .nav-links {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 13px 0;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a.active {
    background: #081D45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a:hover {
    background: #081D45;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i {
    min-width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .nav-links .item {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i.fa-chevron-down {
    right: 1rem;
    left: auto;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
    color: white;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li a .links_name {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.active]="menu.active">
    <ng-container>
      <a class="item" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
        <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i>
        <span class="links_name">{{ menu.name }}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </a>
      <ul
        class="submenu"
        #submenu
        [ngStyle]="{ 'height': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight + 'px' : 0 + 'px' } "
      >
        <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
          <a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }} "
            ><span class="links_subname">{{ submenu.name }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a reproduction => [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-e2bxvj?file=src/styles.css).

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: `justify-content: start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 13px 0;
}

a.item i.fa-chevron-down {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 30px;
  right: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```css
.sidebar .nav-links li a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 13px 0;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li i.fa-chevron-down {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```